# Kotlin android parcelable

Tags: java, android, kotlin, parcel

I've used auto generated feature of android plugin for android studio and it generated me the following code, but I can't understand why is there need for `final val` for `CREATOR` field ? I see `final` keyword for the first time in kotlin.

```
data class Person(
        val name: String,
        val surname: String
) : Parcelable {
    constructor(source: Parcel): this(source.readString(), source.readString())

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel?, flags: Int) {
        dest?.writeString(name)
        dest?.writeString(surname)
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmField final val CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator<Person> = object : Parcelable.Creator<Person> {
            override fun createFromParcel(source: Parcel): Person {
                return Person(source)
            }

            override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Person?> {
                return arrayOfNulls(size)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Kotlin [classes and members are final by default](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#wait-how-will-i-hack-my-libraries-now). In other words the following declarations have the same bytecode:

```
@JvmField final val CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator<Person> = PersonCreator()
@JvmField val CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator<Person> = PersonCreator()
```

So while the generated code has `final` keyword and it is not an error it is redundant.

Even though classes and members are final by default there are still a need for `final` modifier in Kotlin. One example would be to mark `open` method as `final` in derived class:

```
open class Base {
    open fun test(){}
}

open class DerivedA : Base(){
    final override fun test(){}
}

class DerivedB : DerivedA() {
    override fun test(){} //error: 'test' in 'DerivedA' is final and cannot be overriden
}
```

While it's a good practice to make `public static` field `final` in java there's [no strict requirement for the `Parccelable.Creator` field](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) to be marked as such:

> Classes implementing the Parcelable interface must also have a
>   non-null static field called CREATOR of a type that implements the
>   Parcelable.Creator interface.

Answer (score 7):

In Kotlin you can use the `@Parcelize` Kotlin Android Extension:

```
@Parcelize
data class User(val id: String, val name: String) : Parcelable
```

This is a compiler plugin that automatically generates the [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable) implementation for you.

[This page](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#parcelable-implementations-generator) on the Kotlin docs gives more details about it, including requirements, [supported types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#supported-types) and how to create [custom parcelers](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#custom-parcelers) for unsupported types.

---

If you are curious and you want dive into the technical details of the implementation, see the Kotlin Evolution and Enhancement Process [*Compiler Extension to Support `android.os.Parcelable`*](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/extensions/android-parcelable.md).

---

This feature was [experimental until Kotlin 1.3.40](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.3.40/ChangeLog.md#tools-android-extensions). If you are still using a Kotlin version earlier than 1.3.40, you need to enable the experimental features to use this:

```
android {
    // Enable @Parcelize
    // You only need this for Kotlin < 1.3.40
    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use @Parcelize annotation to data class and extends Parcelable. Kotlin automatically do the rest for you. Example- Person data class.

```
@Parcelize
data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int, val email: String) : Parcelable
```

You can send value lets press on a button click like below from an activity.

```
   private val PERSON = "person"

   // first ensure a person object with data
   val person = Person("Shihab Uddin", 30, "shihab.mi7@gmai.com")

   binding.buttonSend.setOnClickListener {

        val intent = Intent(this, ReceiveParcelableAcitivty::class.java)
        //then put an parcelable extra to intent 
        intent.putExtra(PERSON, person)
        startActivity(intent)

    }
```

Receivers activity will get the data like

```
    private val PERSON = "person"
    intent?.let {
        var person = intent.extras.getParcelable(PERSON) as Person
        bind.textViewData.text = " Data Receive: $person"
    }
```

**androidExtensions** attribute is no more necessary < kotlin 1.3.40

```
android {

    // You only need this for Kotlin < 1.3.40
    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the latest kotlin and gradle versions (sorry ,i forgot the version number), you need add

```
plugins {
     id("kotlin-parcelize")
}
```

in this file `build.gradle.kts`( Depends on whether your gradle is kotlin or other)

now , you can use it.

```
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize

@Parcelize
data class User(val id: String, val name: String) : Parcelable
```